# javascript onDOMContentLoaded doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, html

Any ideas why this code doesn't work?

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onDOMContentLoaded=function(){
            alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

onDOMContentLoaded is expected to triogger when the webpage is loaded and make that alert but it doesn't work dunno why

Comment: +1 for summing up how I feel whenever programming in JavaScript: *'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'*!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be binding to the event with `addEventListener`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qHa4T/1

Keep in mind that both `addEventListener` and `DOMContentLoaded` won't work with IE8 and below.